# Merge two array elements with same sizeof third array without eliminating duplicate elements

Tags: c, arrays

Input :

```
arr1[5] = { 4, 2, 7, 3, 1};  
arr2[5] = {9, 3, 6, 1, 10};
```

Output:

```
arr3[5] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3};
```

Problem can be solved if we merge both arrays `int arr3[10]` and sort in ascending order and take only first `5` elements.
But here I do not want to initialize `arr` size `10` (`arr3[10]`).

Comment: why don't you sort your two array and collect five of the smallest elem into a third array ?

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: Copy one of the arrays (A1) into your target array (T). Sort it. Then, for each element of your second original array (A2), insert the element into T if it is smaller than the largest value in T.... For the insertion, you can either insert into the correct location in T by using an adaptation of an insertion sort, or you can replace the top value in T and then re-sort T.

Comment: Somebody please make an answer to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Are you allowed to temporarily create arrays (at least a size 5)? Can you sort the input arrays (or are they const)? Please give feedback on the asnwer-comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int arr1[5] = { 4, 2, 7, 3, 1};
int arr2[5] = {9, 3, 6, 1, 10};
int arr3[5];
int previousSmallest = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int j;
    int smallest = INT_MAX; // I assume you are working with positive ints only
    int smallestCount = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (arr1[j] < smallest && arr1[j] > previousSmallest) {
            smallest = arr1[j];
            smallestCount = 1;
        } else if (arr1[j] == smallest) {
            smallestCount++;
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (arr2[j] < smallest && arr2[j] > previousSmallest) {
            smallest = arr2[j];
            smallestCount = 1;
        } else if (arr2[j] == smallest) {
            smallestCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < smallestCount; k++) {
        arr3[i++] = smallest;
    }
    i--;

    previousSmallest = smallest;
}

for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++)
    printf("%d\n", arr3[l]);
```

However, I hope this exercise is more of a nutcracker than anything. It would always be better to use that extra memory and make things quite faster.

Apologies if this isn't as efficient as it could be, but it works and I sketched it in a few minutes. Hope it helps.

PS: Don't forget to include limits.h

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple and straightforward situation. All you need to do, is to sort the 2 given arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`. Then take the 5 overall least elements from both. I have attached the code below. I have tested and it works like a charm.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int arr1[5] = { 4, 2, 7, 3, 1};  
  int arr2[5] = {9, 3, 6, 1, 10};
  int arr3[5];
  int i, j, k = 0, temp;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
  {
    for (j = i + 1; j < 5; ++j)
    {
      if (arr1[i] > arr1[j]) 
      {
        temp =  arr1[i];
        arr1[i] = arr1[j];
        arr1[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
  {
    for (j = i + 1; j < 5; ++j)
    {
      if (arr2[i] > arr2[j]) 
      {
        temp =  arr2[i];
        arr2[i] = arr2[j];
        arr2[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  i = 0, j = 0;
  while(i < 5 && j < 5 && k < 5) {
    if(arr1[i] <= arr2 [j]) {
      arr3[k++] = arr1[i++];
    }
    else {
      arr3[k++] = arr2[j++];
    }
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d  ",arr3[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```